# Magento Multi Store Customer Combined Login Credentials

Tags: magento

I have just added another website to my Magento eCommerce site and I would like my existing customer bass to be able to login to the new website with the same username and password that they have registered with for the original site. I also need any customer who signs up in the future to be assigned to both websites.

When I go to edit a user there is a drop-down box to say which website they are associated with, but the field is disabled and doesn't look like a multi select drop-down. Which would suggest to me that Magento isn't set up to share details between websites.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the admin, under **System** > **Configuration** > **Customers** > **Customer Configuration** > **Account Sharing Options**, you'll be able to choose between sharing accounts per website or globally.

Comment: There is problem however that the customer cannot subscribe to infdividual newsletters of the different stores